# fills password and enters program automatically

Tags: windows-7

I am running Windows 7. In Internet Explorer 9, when I visit a webpage and enter a password it is automatically remembered. When I leave the site and return again at another time, the password is filled in automatically. I would like to stop this behavior. I **do not not think that it is an auto fill** problem. I think it may be related to an addon provided by my OEM and published by Authentic called "Truesuite Website Log On".

1. How can I confirm that Truesuite is the culprit?
2. How can I stop passwords from being filled in automatically.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the addon?

Answer (score 0):

This is only the first part. 
Clear the browsers/systems own form and password filling items off the disk to confirm that it is a 3rd party item.

Get into the **Internet Options** , In the **General** Tab , in the **Browsing History** section, and hit the **Delete** button.  Dont worry in IE9 it wont bite , you have to select everything you want to delete first. Delete everything, or guess which items need delete, and delete just those, Make sure **Preserve favorite website** is **not** checked , when trying to determine if you exterminated everything.

Still in internet options , Switch to the **Content** tab , in the **Auto Complete** section, and hit **Settings** and delete the autocomplete history again.

That should be enough to test the systems own storage of that stuff for the browser, so now you see if that stuff is stored still.

next try and find a standard Add-On. In the browser select the menu item **tools** and Select **Manage Add-Ons** and see what is up with 3rd party add on items.